# Move the primary store out of the hosting to a new install on a different server and keep the secondary store/website still working on the old server?

Tags: magento-1.9, multidomain, domain

```
Magento 1.9.1
Magento 1.9.4
Porto theme
```

We are moving to a new server. Our old store is Magento 1.9.1. I exported all products and imported them into the new Magento 1.9.4 on the new server. I've also already setup the design, categories and everything else. The idea was to move the primary website/store with the secondary together at the same time. Now we changed our mind and we would like to continue running the secondary website/store on the old hosting platform and the new one on the new server. Will that work when I redirect the primary domain to resolve on the new server? We have the secondary website/store setup this way:

https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains

(the secondary domain is parked in the Cpanel and configured in  the .htaccess file like this:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1_com
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1_com
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2_com
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2_com
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes that should work.
If you change the A-records for the domain of your primary store (e.g. domain1.com and www.domain1.com) in the DNS server to point to the IP address of your new server
you should get wat you need:

All requests for your primary store are routed to the new server.

All requests for your secondary domain (e.g. domain2.com and www.domain2.com) are still routed to the old server.